# Validate the inline jqgrid row before saving

Tags: jqgrid

I want to show the validation message with OK CANCEL button when i update the current row and move on to other row without saving the current row. Say my validation message "Do you want save the changes?"

1.if CANCEL button clicks it should restore the row content.

2.if OK button clicks it should remains in edit mode with updated values.

Please help me to achieve this..

Comment: Look at [the old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39368653/315935). I think that it provides the solution of your problem. The answer provides two demos: [the first one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-promptSaveOnSelect0.htm) and [the second one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-promptSaveOnSelect.htm), which demonstrates the corresponding implementation.

Comment: Thanks a lot Oleg. Helpfull comment.